# Reading a SSTable in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, nosql

Sorted Strings Table is a file of key/value string pairs, sorted by keys

But it is not clear what fields SSTable entity (class) should have

Should we store all values?

It is clear that we save the shift for each key, but I still cannot fully understand how to store all this

After reading a good article, I still don't fully understand: https://www.igvita.com/2012/02/06/sstable-and-log-structured-storage-leveldb/